# PyQGIS in standalone scripts on Mac, import error

Tags: python, pyqgis, file-path, pyqt5, importerror

Following the PyQGIS Developer Cookbook to use PyQGIS in standalone scripts. Fixed the initial errors by setting the PYTHONPATH and DYLD_PYTHON_PATH to the appropriate folders but am now faced with the error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/PyQt5/QtCore.so, 2): Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/QtCore
  Referenced from: /Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/Resources/python/PyQt5/QtCore.so
  Reason: image not found
```

It loads fine in the QGIS interpreter, and I ran sys.path in QGIS, then ran sys.path.append in my external interpreter for every path that QGIS is connected with from the sys.path results, but no luck. I've found the QtCore.so image but directing the path to that file also doesn't work.

Does anybody know how to get around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usage of `@executable_path` is the limitation of the current all-in-one MacOS QGIS bundle.

Your executable must be in `/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/bin` folder so the `@executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/QtCore` is expanded to `/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/QtCore` where the library exists

Do you run the script with `/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/python3`?

see [this link for explanation](https://wincent.com/wiki/@executable_path,_@load_path_and_@rpath) and you can use `otool -L <library/executable>` to list loaded libraries

Comment: Brilliant! Running the script in  /Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/python3 works fine. Frustrating to spend all that time trying to connect paths when the answer was to use the correct QGIS python version in an external interpreter. Thanks so much!